# JSON elasticsearch parsing

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am new to the ELK. I have the stack running and i have imported json object into the elasticsearch, it is a nested object.

This is how the collapsed object looks like:

```
{
"mapping": {
"properties": {
"alert": {
"appliance": {
"appliance-id": {
"msg": {
"product": {
"version": {
  }
 }
}
```

I can see each of the indexed filed on kibana. The problem is 'alert' field has dozens of field that i am interested in and would like to see it indexed and searchable on kibana. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the complete mapping from the index:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "alert": {
        "properties": {
          "ack": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "action": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "alert-url": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "dst": {
            "properties": {
              "smtp-to": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "explanation": {
            "properties": {
              "analysis": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "malware-detected": {
                "properties": {
                  "malware": {
                    "properties": {
                      "domain": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "downloaded-at": {
                        "type": "date"
                      },
                      "executed-at": {
                        "type": "date"
                      },
                      "md5sum": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "sha256": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "sid": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "stype": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "submitted-at": {
                        "type": "date"
                      },
                      "type": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "protocol": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "interface": {
            "properties": {
              "interface": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "mode": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "occurred": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "sc-version": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "severity": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "smtp-message": {
            "properties": {
              "date": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "last-malware": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "protocol": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "smtp-header": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "subject": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "src": {
            "properties": {
              "domain": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "smtp-mail-from": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "url": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "uuid": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "appliance": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "appliance-id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "msg": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "product": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "version": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to share an example of your alert field. What is not working? What you want to do? How are you indexing your data?

Answer (score 0):

In order for Elastic Search to understand that a field is of nested type you need to explicitly mention the **"type":"nested"** in the mapping, otherwise on dynamic mapping the field will be considered as an object array by default.

Correct me , if I am wrong from your question what I can understand is the "alert" field is a nested type field with properties - "appliance","appliance-id","msg","product" and "version" etc ,So your mapping should look like :

```
{
    "mapping": {
        "properties": {
            "alert": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "ack": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "action": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "alert-url": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "dst": {
                        "properties": {
                            "smtp-to": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "explanation": {
                        "properties": {
                            "analysis": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "malware-detected": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "malware": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "domain": {
                                                "type": "text",
                                                "fields": {
                                                    "keyword": {
                                                        "type": "keyword",
                                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "downloaded-at": {
                                                "type": "date"
                                            },
                                            "executed-at": {
                                                "type": "date"
                                            },
                                            "md5sum": {
                                                "type": "text",
                                                "fields": {
                                                    "keyword": {
                                                        "type": "keyword",
                                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "name": {
                                                "type": "text",
                                                "fields": {
                                                    "keyword": {
                                                        "type": "keyword",
                                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "sha256": {
                                                "type": "text",
                                                "fields": {
                                                    "keyword": {
                                                        "type": "keyword",
                                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "sid": {
                                                "type": "text",
                                                "fields": {
                                                    "keyword": {
                                                        "type": "keyword",
                                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "stype": {
                                                "type": "text",
                                                "fields": {
                                                    "keyword": {
                                                        "type": "keyword",
                                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "submitted-at": {
                                                "type": "date"
                                            },
                                            "type": {
                                                "type": "text",
                                                "fields": {
                                                    "keyword": {
                                                        "type": "keyword",
                                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "protocol": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "interface": {
                        "properties": {
                            "interface": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "mode": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "occurred": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "sc-version": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "severity": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "smtp-message": {
                        "properties": {
                            "date": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "last-malware": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "protocol": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "smtp-header": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "subject": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "src": {
                        "properties": {
                            "domain": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "smtp-mail-from": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "url": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "uuid": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "appliance": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "appliance-id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "msg": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "product": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "version": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While insertion, you can optionally have any of the properties mentioned under alerts ,and if dynamic mapping is enabled, and there is a new property , it will also be added automatically in the nested field "alert"'s property list. Any queries on these properties will need to be made using nested queries where you will need to first give the dotted path to the nested field like "path":"alert"   (in this alert is not a sub field and so no need of giving any dots in the path) 
reference - https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-beginner-troubleshooting#keyvalue-woes 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-nested-query.html